# Sending API data using Link in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am making a stock portfolio project using Gatsby and a stockmarket API. Currently, when you search by a ticker-symbol it returns the ticker-symbol, market cap, and previous close in a table. When you click on the returned ticker-symbol it brings you to another page. On this next page, I would like to have access to the same API search just to display more details of the stock.

I was told last night here on StackOverflow I could send API data through Link however after looking through some documentation I am not sure how to implement specifically what I described.

I do not mind switching details.js to a class component, I had tried that earlier and setting state up but I just had a plethora of different errors.

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from "axios"
import "../css/style.css"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { symbol } from "prop-types"

export default class index extends React.Component {
  state = {
      companyName: "",
      previousClose: "",
      marketCap: "",
      change: "",
      symbol: "",
      topStocks: []

  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const API_KEY = '******************';
    axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/previous?token=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => {

        console.log(res)

        const topStocks = res.slice(1);
        this.setState({ topStocks })

      })
  }


  clickHandler = (event) => {
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          const query = event.target.value;
          const API_KEY = '******************';
      axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${query}/quote?token=${API_KEY}`)
          .then(res => {
              const companyName = res.data['companyName'];
              this.setState({ companyName })

              const previousClose = res.data['previousClose'];
              this.setState({ previousClose })

              const marketCap = res.data['marketCap'];
              this.setState({ marketCap })

              const change = res.data['change'];
              this.setState({ change })

              const symbol = res.data['symbol'];
              this.setState({ symbol })
          })
      }
  }



  render() {
      return (
          <Layout>
              <div class = "main-div">
                  <input type="search" class="main-search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)}/>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Ticker-Symbol</th>
                      <th>Market Cap</th>
                      <th>Previous Close</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Link to='/details/' state={{setState: this.state.symbol, query: `yourQuery`}}>{this.state.symbol}</Link></td>
                      <td>{this.state.marketCap}</td>
                      <td>{this.state.previousClose}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div>
                {
                  this.state.topStocks.length && this.state.topStocks.map(stock => (
                  <h1>{stock.symbol}</h1>
                  ))
                }
              </div>
          </Layout>
      )
  }
}
```

details.js

```
//import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

const Details = props => {
  const [yourState, setYourState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.location.state.someState) {
      axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/XOM/quote?token=******************`)
        .then(res => setYourState(res))


    }
  }, []);

  return <Layout>
    <div>

      </div>
      </Layout>;
    };

export default Details;
```

The errors with my current code are:

```
D:\Web Development\React JS course\gatsby-site\src\pages\details.js
  7:5   error  React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "details" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  7:5   error  'useEffect' is not defined                                                                                                          no-undef
  8:12  error  Unexpected use of 'location'                                                                                                        no-restricted-globals
  9:65  error  'query' is not defined                                                                                                              no-undef

✖ 4 problems (4 errors, 0 warnings)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things, because you have a little weird component/page there.

1. You are not importing `useEffect` in your `details.js` page as error shows:

   > 7:5   error  'useEffect' is not defined
2. Your state passed through `<Link>` component needs to be retrieved via `props` (or destructuring `props` and getting `location` directly).
3. `details.js` is a functional component, you don't have a `setState` (nor `this`) function there. Use `useState` hook instead.
4. `query` parameter is never provided to this component. Once you solve the main issues you should pass it via `props`.

   > error  'query' is not defined
5. Your components are not camelCased.

All errors should fixed with:

```
//import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

const Details = props => {
  const [yourState, setYourState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.location.state.someState) {
      axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${props.location.state.query}/quote?token=*****************`)
        .then(res => setYourState(res))
    }
  }, []);

  return <Layout>
    <div>
      {/*do stuff with your yourState. (i.e: console.log('hi!', yourState))*/}
        </div>
      </Layout>;
    };

export default Details;
```

Regarding the second and third points:

1. `const Details= props => {}` equals to `const Details= ({ location }) => {}`.
   This destructuring saves you one step and get directly `location` object instead of doing `props.location` in your condition.
2. Your `setState` function is not allowed in functional components rather than class components. It's entirely up to you choosing whether one or another, but you need to be aware of their "limitations" and "benefits". In this case, you need to use `useState` hook. As you can see it's composed by `const [yourState, setYourState]`. The second element (`setYourState`) is the function that will be used to store the value of `yourState`, so, your axios asynchronous request will be stored using `setYourState` function and retrieved via `yourState`. Of course, you can name it whatever you wish.
3. From your `index.js`, update the state and set the `query`: `` <Link to='/details/' state={{setState: this.state.symbol, query: `yourQuery`}}/> ``

Recommended readings:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

If you need a detailed explanation on any point please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216266/discussion-on-answer-by-ferran-buireu-sending-api-data-using-link-in-gatsby).